# get_permalink for linking to specific place in a page

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I am trying to link to specific place in a page from my front page , now I can only link to all page like this

```
<a class="info" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink(1770) ); ?>" > Click to Explore </a>
```

but I want instead of page , link to exact place in a page, like in the middle , because in the page I use accordion and each panel of accordion are specific article , so I want to exact article. Is it possible to add to pageID 1770 some more information to do this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Read up about anchors

Answer (score 1):

As @mszymborski said, use anchors.

Add an ID to the section/location of where you want the page to scroll to.

e.g. `<h2 id="specific-location">Heading 2</h2>`

in the code you provided, add the anchor name (#specific-location) at the end of the href.

```
<a class="info" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink(1770) ); ?>#specific-location" > Click to Explore </a>
```

Comment: The think is that its again link to all page not opening the second panel for instance. I tried to add anchor in different places , like <h2> , body of panel or just some random <p> inside of panel . So is it only possible to go to body of panel when you click on panel ? I used bootstrap accordion. Thanks Peter .

Comment: It can be used anywhere. Just attach an ID to the tag. If you want to open the second panel you will need to use javascript to detect the anchor tag and open the accordion via jquery. Please update your post with your bootstrap accordion code.

Comment: Yes Peter exactly  , I need some jquery code for opening the panel which is not by default opened , so dont have class "in" , actually none of this panels open by default . Sorry I couldnt enter the code with bootstrap , some errors , I am new here ..

Comment: Please try to fix the bootstrap panel code and post it.